# track user's data entry using SQL

Tags: sql

i have a table where i track data inserted from users that contains the following:

| FS_ID | user |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | user1 |
| 11111 | user1 |
| 22222 | user1 |
| 22222 | user1 |
| 22222 | user1 |
| 33333 | user2 |
| 33333 | user2 |

however, i know that user1 has typed 5 records, but only 2 FS_ID (11111 and 22222), and user2 2 rocrds but only one FS_ID(33333).

my question is,using SQL Query: how to count for each user, how many unique FS_ID has typed

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY.

Comment: Can you share your current query by updating your post?

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
SELECT t.user, COUNT(DISTINCT t.FS_ID) FROM your_table t
GROUP BY t.user
```